# Files not getting unzipped, output of the task is UP TO DATE

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have two gradle tasks:

```
task getDistributionValues {
    fileTree(dir: 'build/tmp/distribution/', include: '*.zip').visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
        distributionZips << details.file.name
        println('printvalues'+distributionZips)
    }
}

getDistributionValues.dependsOn(getDistribution)
def distributionComponentName

task unzipDistribution(type:Copy){
    distributionZips.each { unzipNames ->
        distributionComponentName = unzipNames.substring(0,unzipNames.length()-15)
        println('comp Name here'+distributionComponentName)
        def zipFile = file('build/tmp/distribution/'+unzipNames)
        into project.buildDir
        from(zipTree(zipFile)) {
            into 'tmp/unzipComponent/'+distributionComponentName
       }
    }
}
unzipDistribution.dependsOn(getDistributionValues)
```

I have two zip files in distribuition folder that I am getting by executing one task.
Ideally,as a result of these tasks, I should be getting the unzipped files but I don't get any output. Any suggestions?
The names of these files in distribution folder are bc-bluetooth-0.8.0-dist.zip and bc-core-0.6.3-dist.zip

Comment: That's only 2 gradle tasks isn't it?

Comment: yes . Only 2 gradle tasks

Comment: Want me to edit the line _"I have three gradle tasks:"_?

Comment: I changed that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are zip files in `~/tmp/distribution`, the following works for me with Gradle 2.12:

```
def distributionZips = []

def performDistribution = { ->
    // copy zip files from ~/tmp/distribution to ~/build/tmp/distribution
    ant.mkdir(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/distribution")
    ant.copy(todir: "${buildDir}/tmp/distribution") {
        fileset(dir: "${projectDir}/tmp/distribution", includes: "*.zip")
    }

    // populate distributionZips
    fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/distribution", include: '*.zip').visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
        distributionZips << details.file.name
        println 'printvalues: ' + distributionZips
    }
}

task getDistributionValues() << {
    performDistribution()
}

def distributionComponentName

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == "unzipDistribution") {
        performDistribution()
    }
}

task unzipDistribution(type:Copy) {
    distributionZips.each { unzipNames ->
        distributionComponentName = unzipNames.replace(".zip", "")
        println('comp Name here'+distributionComponentName)
        def zipFile = file('build/tmp/distribution/'+unzipNames)
        into project.buildDir
        from(zipTree(zipFile)) {
            into 'tmp/unzipComponent/'+distributionComponentName
        }
    }
}
```

The primary issue is that this:

```
task unzipDistribution(type: Copy) {
    // executed during Configuration phase
}
```

had a mix of code involving the Configuration phase and Execution phase. (I use the ICE rule: Initialization, Configuration, Execution, as [documented here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)).

My solution is just one way to do it, but it uses a Groovy method that is used by `getDistributionValues` during Execution phase and also by `unzipDistribution` during Configuration phase.